# Why doesn't React Native component rerender on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to dynamically change `display` property of an element. I created a component, but it doesn't rerender, when state is updated. I know that function `toggleDisplay` executes, as it logs `displayState` to the console. What am I missing?

```
  class DetailedInfo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   
      this.state = {
        displayState: 'flex',
      };
    }

      toggleDisplay = () => {
          if (this.state.displayState=='flex') {
              this.setState(state => ({displayState: 'none'}))
          } else {
            this.setState(state => ({display: this.state.toggleDisplay}))
          }

          console.log(this.state.displayState);
          this.forceUpdate()
      }

      render() {
        return (
              <ScrollView>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleDisplay}>
                      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 500}}>
                          <Text style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                          Lorem Ipsum
                          </Text>
                      </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              </ScrollView>
        )
      }
  };
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you should not ever have to call `forceUpdate()`, unless you have some dependencies external to your component's props and state. instead let `setState()` and react's component life cycle handle that for you. [See additional notes](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you are not using the state variable for style

`<Text style={{display: this.state.dispalyState }}>`

2. Change toggle display method slightly

```
  toggleDisplay = () => {
      if (this.state.displayState=='flex') {
          this.setState({displayState: 'none'})
      } else {
        this.setState({displayState: 'flex'}))
      }

      console.log(this.state.displayState);
      this.forceUpdate()
  }
```

Comment: Works like charm now. Thanks a lot!